# How to extract only the integer value instead of the Double value when reading data from Excel using Java

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, double

I need a code which should get data from Excel as int values instead of String values.

It is displaying the value `2.0` which was originally saved in sheet as 2`

Try 1:

```
HSSFCell number = sheet.getRow(1).getCell(26);
Integer result =Integer.valueOf(number);                
System.out.println(result);
```

Try 2:

```
int L = Integer.parseInt(getRow(1).getCell(26));

Error:The method parseInt(String) in the type Integer is not applicable for the arguments (Cell)
```

Code:

```
System.out.println(+sheet.getRow(1).getCell(26));
```

Output: 2.0

Expected output : 2

Comment: You can cast it with System.out.println((int) (+sheet.getRow(1).getCell(26)));

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend the following way, which does not try to cast an `HSSFCell` to an `Integer`/`int`:

```
// get the cell as object (this is NOT a number, instead, it contains one)
HSSFCell numberCell = sheet.getRow(1).getCell(26);
// get the cell value as double (there is no direct integer version)
double cellValue = numberCell.getNumericCellValue();
// cast the value to an int
int number = (int) cellValue;
```

Comment: Thank you so much deHaar. This Worked for me. @deHaar

Comment: @RohithGoud you're welcome! Consider accepting my answer, you will get a little reputation for accepting an answer, too.

Comment: Hi @deHaar, IS there any code which can get the date as the following Format "dd-MMM-uuuu"" which is imported from the Excel.  when i tried to get the date  using '   LocalDate.parse(sheet.getRow(1).getCell(13) ,DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd-MMM-uuuu" , Locale.US )).toString();' , it is giving we Error as "The method parse(CharSequence, DateTimeFormatter) in the type LocalDate is not applicable for the arguments (XSSFCell, DateTimeFormatter)". Please give me a solution

Comment: @RohithGoud you are not parsing the content of the cell (`String`) but the cell itself (`XSSFCell`), change that. Do `LocalDate.parse(sheet.getRow(1).getCell(13).getStringCellValue() ,DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd-MMM-uuuu" , Locale.US )).toString();`

Answer (score 2):

Once you read the **Double** values from the excel instead of displaying the values as **2.0**, to print it as **2** you can use the [DecimalFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) *Class* methods and you can use the following solution:

```
HSSFCell number = sheet.getRow(1).getCell(26);
Double result =Double.valueOf(number);                
DecimalFormat format = new DecimalFormat();
format.setDecimalSeparatorAlwaysShown(false);
System.out.println(format.format(result));
```

Incase your usecase is to print the *String* format you can add `String.valueOf()` and you can use the following solution:

```
HSSFCell number = sheet.getRow(1).getCell(26);
Double result =Double.valueOf(number);                
DecimalFormat format = new DecimalFormat();
format.setDecimalSeparatorAlwaysShown(false);
System.out.println(String.valueOf(format.format(result)));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
int L = Integer.parseInt(getRow(1).getCell(26).getStringCellValue());
```